# C++ lambda as templated parameter of a function not working

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to pass a lambda into a parameter in the maybe() function, which is working strangely.  Code is below:

```
template<typename R, typename F>
void maybe(R& result, F& lambda) {
    if (0 == result) {  
        result = lambda();
    }
}

auto l = [&]() {
    return adi_uart_Open(deviceNum, ADI_UART_DIR_BIDIRECTION, &memory, ADI_UART_BIDIR_DMA_MEMORY_SIZE, &handle);
};
```

If I call

```
maybe(result, l);
```

then everything works just fine.  However, if I put the lamba into the function directly, like:

```
maybe(result, [&](){return adi_uart_Open(deviceNum, ADI_UART_DIR_BIDIRECTION, &memory, ADI_UART_BIDIR_DMA_MEMORY_SIZE, &handle);});
```

then I get the following error:

> error: no instance of function template "maybe" matches the argument list

I'd use std::function instead of templates, but it's not available on the embedded device i'm working on.

Comment: `F&` is a non-`const` lvalue reference, it cannot bind to your temporary lambda. Use `F const &` or `F&&`.

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/5470596 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maybe` takes an lvalue reference:

```
maybe(R& result, F& lambda)
```

C++ forbids a non-const lvalue reference to be bound to a temporary. Add a const.

```
maybe(R& result, F const& lambda)
```